# Stop Makefile when there is an inadvertent circular dependency

Tags: makefile

**Problem**

Here is a short Makefile with a circular dependency introduced by inadvertence.

```
egg : chicken
chicken : egg

egg chicken foo :
    @touch $@
```

When launching `make egg`, Makefile detects the circular dependency, drops it and executes the recipe. I would like to stop the execution of the recipe.

**Clumsy solution**

So far, the best solution I found is the following:

```
egg : chicken
chicken : egg

egg chicken foo :
    @mqe=`make --question $@ 2>&1 > /dev/null`; \
    if [ -z "$$mqe" ]; then \
        touch $@ ; \
    else \
        echo "*** ERROR *** $$mqe" ; false ; \
    fi
```

Is there a more elegant way to stop Makefile when a circular dependency is detected ?

**Context**

The example I gave is really simplified. The real project is a huge Fortran code where circular dependencies on modules are introduced by inadvertence and are not detected by sfmakedepend.

Comment: There is no way to force make to stop processing when it sees a circular dependency.  As a completely separate topic, be sure you always use `$(MAKE)` when invoking a sub-make, never the raw `make`.

Comment: The only other method I can think of is to first build into a temporary folder and then check if `make`saw a circular dependency, moving or renaming the temporary folder to the official build folder if all went well. This may be infeasible with respect to the rest of your build process tho.